# How to enable "relaxed" memory model mode for Kotlin/Native?

Tags: kotlin-native

To workaround the InvalidMutabilityException

As mentioned in this https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-native-1-3-50-relaxed-mode/13586

Comment: As stated in the topic you shared, it is experimental and unready, for now at least. It's purpose quietly differs from "workaround the InvalidMutabilityException", it's more about "deal with some very special corner cases". Are you sure that your problem cannot be solved in the strict model? If so, maybe it would make sense to share in the K/N Github or even here.

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev it's not impossible but it's very hard to work with. Objects get frozen unexpectedly, can only detect on runtime, have to rewrite many parts,...

Comment: Yep, it can be an unpleasant work to migrate if you already have some Kotlin/JVM code. But, I'm sure that it can be done in the current memory model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with the compiler flag `-memory-model relaxed`. Please avoid using this feature in production, as the model is still in the experimental stage of development.

Comment: Any idea how to accompish this in build.gradle?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a good idea, @WernerAltewischer, but you can try to set the compiler flag in the `.freeCompilerArgs` property of a binary configuration.

Comment: @WernerAltewischer You can add `kotlin.native.binary.memoryModel=experimental` to `gradle.properties` to accomplish this